# Non standard method of solving differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I Have a differential equation:

$$ (7y -3 ) dx + (2x + 1) dy = 0 $$

I'm trying to solve this equation in non standard way, because I'd like to use the other method of solving in this case.

Since the coefficients of $ dx $ and $ dy $ are assumed to define line in the plain, so:

$$ 7y - 3 = 0 $$
$$ 2x + 1 = 0 $$

Of course the point of the intersection of these lines is: $ (\frac{-1}{2},\frac{3}{7})  $.

Next I'm trying to move origin of the plain to the above mentioned intersection point, where point $ (\frac{-1}{2},\frac{3}{7})  $ will be our new origin.

We know that relations between the cooridnates are:

$$ x = \bar{x} - \frac{1}{2}  $$
$$ y = \bar{y} + \frac{3}{7} $$

where $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$ are coordinates measured from $ (\frac{-1}{2},\frac{3}{7})  $.

Next I'm trying to substitute these relationships to differential equation:

$$ (7(\bar{y} + \frac{3}{7}) - 3 ) dx + (2 (\bar{x} - \frac{1}{2}) + 1)dy = 0 $$
And after simplification I'm obtaining equation:
$$ 7 \bar{y}d\bar{x} + 2\bar{x}d\bar{y}  = 0 $$

Now, I'm dividing the equation both sides by $ \bar{x} \bar{y} $ and I'm obtaining:

$$ 7 \frac{d \bar{x}}{\bar{x}} + 2 \frac{d \bar{y}}{\bar{y}}  = 0$$

And I'm obtaining solution:

$$ 7 ln | \bar{x} | + 2 ln | \bar{y} | = c  $$

$$ 7 ln | x + \frac{1}{2} | + 2 ln |y - \frac{3}{7} | = c  $$

I have a problem, because answer from the book to this exercies is:

$$ 2 ln| 7y - 3 | + 7 ln | 2x +1 |  = c  $$

Is my answer wrong?

Comment: you've mixed up your $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ coordinates....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is fine, but at the beginning, you should have done 
$$
x = \bar{x} -\frac12\\y = \bar{y} + \frac37
$$
Also, when checking your answer, remember that the two constants both called "$c$"
need not match, and that $\ln(y-\frac37) =  \ln(7y-3)- \ln 7$ (similarly for $x$ expressions, so things that don't look identical may very well match.

Comment: I've corrected my post. Thanks for help ;) Now I understand all ;)